# Is there an utility that automatically adjust volume based on the background noise?

Tags: windows, android, osx, ios, audio

Assume I listed to music and put kettle on. I would like volume to adjust automatically.

Another case: I listed to a podcast and when my partner is using sewing machine I would like volume to adjust automatically.

Any ideas / recommendations?

(thanks)

UPDATE: As suggested in the comments - adding tags for target platforms. Primarily **OS X** I would say.

Comment: First recommendation: Please [edit] your question and name the target OS :) It certainly makes a difference whether you're needing it for your Windows laptop, an Android smartphone, or an iPad ;)

Comment: I am using OS X, Windows, Android smartphone and iPad... YEAH... I can use all the tags then! :) (thanks for the advice)

Comment: Thanks for the update! I'm not using this myself, but in the meantime added [some Android apps to my list](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=183#group_871) you might wish to check. Good luck!